# How does Unity execute its methods?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I only have a small experience in Unity3D, but I noticed that classes that derive from `MonoBehaviour` may contain functions with predefined signatures that will be called in a special way. For instance, if I write:

```
void Update()
{
  //some code
}
```

this method will be called every frame.

I imagine that inside Unity there is some sort of an endless loop that calls the `Update` method every frame for each object on the scene. But how does it know that the object actually provides the `Update` method implementation? It would have been clear if `Update` was an override for a method in the `MonoBehaviour` class, but judging by the syntax (and the fact that you can implement such methods with any access modifier) it's not. Is there some reflection magic happening there?

Comment: the short anwser is they use preprocessing magic to handle those "quasi-functions". you can google many explanations.  never forget game engines are frame-based systems, it's all a bit different!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/

> No, Unity doesn’t use System.Reflection to find a magic method every
>   time it needs to call one.
>
> Instead, the first time a MonoBehaviour of a given type is accessed
>   the underlying script is inspected through scripting runtime (either
>   Mono or IL2CPP) whether it has any magic methods defined and this
>   information is cached. If a MonoBehaviour has a specific method it is
>   added to a proper list, for example if a script has Update method
>   defined it is added to a list of scripts which need to be updated
>   every frame.
>
> During the game Unity just iterates through these lists and executes
>   methods from it — that simple. Also, this is why it doesn’t matter if
>   your Update method is public or private.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am glad I could help. Cheers. BTW this blog article has much more intresting info.

Comment: So, it turns out they actually *do* use some sort of reflection, just not `System.Reflection`.

Comment: What blog author stated is that they dont use Reflection each time they need to call the magic method. My quess is that with Mono they still use `System.Reflection`.

Comment: It is possible that because of a bad operation or whatever, that list might become empty, and no Update methods are being called? I'm asking because no coroutines and no Update methods are being executed In my project 