# C# Basics - How do interfaces work and calling implemented interface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I desperately need someone to explain me the following case and how it works "under the hood". This would help me understand the concept on a much deeper level.

**Unity case:**

In Unity3D engine, if we want to detect a click on a UI element, we simply implement one of their premade interfaces called "IPointerClickHandler" to our custom class.

```
public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{

  // Do whatever you want in here, when you detect click on UI element
}
```

The script needs to be attached to each individual element, but at the end of the day, it works like a charm.

**My case:**

This is fascinating for me, because I'm not sure how does Unity know that my class implemented one of its interfaces and calling the appropriate method.

I would like to do a similar trick but I can't figure out how. For example, I would like to notify all classes that implement "IScore" listener which has a method "OnScoreChanged(float newScore)";

```
public float Score;

public interface IScore {

    void OnScoreChanged(float newScore);
}



public void SetScore(int newScore) {

    Score = newScore;
   //Notify all classes that implement IScore interface

   // .OnScoreChanged(newScore);
}``
```

I would probably need a reference so my idea is to get all references to classes that implement "OnScoreChanged". Is the above example the right approach and how I can make it work? Basically, I want to implement this interface in the class where I need to get notified about new score and completely forget about how this method is called. Is something like this possible?

```
    public class MyClassB: IScore {
        public void OnScoreChanged(float newScore)
        {
            // This just got called after score 
//changed..and without any additional implementation!
        }
    }
```

P.S I know I can use delegates with events (and then subscribe to this event from other classes), but I'm really curious how can Unity just call the interface method and keep the code much cleaner (so the user doesn't subscribe to its events, etc).

Comment: Google: "dependency injection"

Comment: @vzwick This doesn't seem about 'dependency injection' .. "Basically, I want to implement this interface in the class where I need to get notified about new score and completely forgot about how this method is called. Is something like this possible?"

Comment: "Who told you Unity's code is clean?"

Nobody actually but it really looks like it is. Just implementing the interface and doing stuff inside the method is all I need to do in order to make it work. However, I really don't know why and how it works "under the hood".

Comment: Basically, Unity uses a lot of Reflection to detect all instances of the interface. It's clean for you, not the platform itself

Comment: So this is the work of reflection basically? Well..that's an idea.. thank you for this.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Its not *really* reflection, though. It isn't doing runtime lookups for all the scripts that have an `Update` method. It's actually doing that at compile-time and caching the results. When a new instance is created, Unity already knows that that class has an `Update` (or whichever magic method) and stores a reference internally. https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Unity execute its methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010701/how-does-unity-execute-its-methods) as "how does Unity do it" is sort of the implied question here.

Comment: @Draco18s No, it *is* really Reflection. Just because it's called once and not every time it doesn't mean it's not Reflection. Code inspection == Reflection. The blog *never* says nor implies they don't use System.Reflection, that's only what you wanted to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to implement this yourself is to derive all your classes from a single base class.  This base class will invoke the VIRTUAL function `OnWhatever()`.  [Notice: all your custom Unity component classes are derived from Monobehavior.]

Then when you create your derived classes, you can simply override the virtual `OnWhatever()` function, with a version specific to that component.

---

However, if you would like to stick with interfaces only:  you can now use `GetComponents < T >` or `GetComponentsInChildren < T >` and specify an **Interface** for the type to find.    You can go even "wider", in your interface search, by calling the `GetCompoentsInChildren < T > ()` function on ALL the Scene's ["root" Objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.GetRootGameObjects.html).

Then you can simply call/invoke the interface specified `OnWhatever()` function, for ALL the `GetComponents < T >` results.